# how running a windows command (cmd) in a folder specified from java

Tags: java, process, cmd, console, runtime

Good day, I thank who can help me in advance.

I need to run a command to read a file that contains the input data of a program and it will return a file with the output data.

Criteria:

- I must locate myself in the folder where is the executable file of the software, then I write the following command:

  `swmm5 prueba1.inp prueba1.rpt prueba1.out`

If I run it in the cmd, it generates output files:

- swmm5 is the executable file
- test1.inp is the file with the input data
- test1.rpt is an output data file (this file is created when I run the command)
- test1.out is the file with the output data (this file is created when I run the command)

The code I'm trying to use is this, although it generate no errors, it does not run the above command line successfully, because it does not generate the output files. Also I tried with the `String` that is in comments // (comando)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class OptimizarSWMM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime cmd = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proceso;

        String[] directorio = new String[4];
        directorio[0] = "cmd.exe";
        directorio[1] = "/C";
        directorio[2] = "C:\\Users\\milton\\Desktop\\EPA_SWMM_5.1";
        directorio[3] = "swmm5 prueba1.inp prueba1.rpt prueba1.out";


        //String comando = "cmd /C C:\\Users\\milton\\Desktop\\EPA_SWMM_5.1 swmm5 prueba1.inp prueba1.rpt prueba1.out";

        try {
            proceso = cmd.exec(directorio);
            //proceso = cmd.exec(comando);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OptimizarSWMM.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend at the very least getting and reading the error stream of the Process

Comment: Use ProcessBulder, it allows to specify the directory in which the command should be executed

Answer (score 1):

i could solve it thus:

```
"cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\milton\\Desktop\\EPA_SWMM_5.1\" && swmm5 prueba1.inp prueba1.rpt prueba1.out"
```

this is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\milton\\Desktop\\EPA_SWMM_5.1\" && swmm5 prueba1.inp prueba1.rpt prueba1.out");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
```